# get data from HTML table dynamically generated

Tags: javascript, php, html

i'm new to Html , php , javascript. I'm using a table generated from mysql query:

```
<?php
    session_start ();
    require_once ('auth.php');
    require_once ('connection.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table id="example">
        <?php               
            $result = $mysqli->query ( "Select name ,date from table" );
            while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc () ) {
                echo "<tr>".
                        "<td>" . $row ['name'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row ['date'] . "</td>
                     </tr>";
            }
            $result->free ();
        ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now i want to select a row , redirect to another page transferring data from the selected row to the new page. Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you tell what data you want to transfer and what basically do you want to do another page? e.g. do you want to have an Edit button in each row and clicking on it you will open a form in the new page to edit the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   <?php
        session_start ();
        require_once ('auth.php');
        require_once ('connection.php');
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>

        <body>
            <table id="example">
            <?php               
                $result = $mysqli->query ( "Select name ,date from table" );
                while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc () ) {
                    $url = "second.php?name={$row ['name']}&date={$row ['date']}";
                    echo "<tr>".
                            "<td><a href=\"<?=$url?>\">" . $row ['name'] . "</a></td>
                             <td><a href=\"<?=$url?>\">" . $row ['date'] . "</a></td>
                         </tr>";
                }
                $result->free ();
            ?>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Where second.php is the action page where you can get the passed parameters name and date using $_GET['name'], $_GET['date'] respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I would additionally select the `id` (if the table has any) or any other unique key. Then in the output you can add a link to something like `display.php?id=X` with `X` being the unique key from this row.

Then, in the `display.php` you can just use the query `"SELECT name, date FROM table WHERE id = " . intval($_GET['id']) . "` to select the single row and display it just like you did on the other page.